# How to add COUNT to a sub query that contains a case when

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

We have the following query

```
 select
        ELG
      , UHID
      , BED
      , DIAGNOSIS
      , Specialisation
      , AdmitDate
      , LOS
      , DischargeDate
      , REMARKS
      , Name
      , (
               select
                      case
                             when BedName      like 'INCUBATOR%'
                                    or BedName like 'NS%'
                                    then 1
                                    else (cast (WardID as varchar(20)))
                      END AS NewBorn
        )
        NewBron
      , (
               select
                      case
                             when LOS<=1
                                    then 1
                                    else (cast (los as varchar(20)))
                      end as DayCase
        )
        DayCase
 from
        DischargeWard
```

that gives the following output 
[image]

for the last two columns 'NewBorn' 'DayCase' i want it to get the count , for example for the NewBorn column it would be 3 and for the DayCase it would be 5 , I'm not sure how can i do that due to having other columns with multiple data , please note that I'll be using the query to create a crystal report .

Comment: MySql is not Sql Server! Decide which one you are using.

Comment: No one can read your mind nor does anyone know your system. What logic do you want to use to generate the value of 3 for NewBorn? Does that value apply to every row? Just some rows? You want the count - OF WHAT? Same comments apply to your other column. And note - sloppy work for a developer is not an encouraging sign. Your code clearly produces a column named NewBorn while your image has NewBron. Your inconsistent approach to defining the datatype of your calculated columns is also problematic. A string? A number?

Comment: Dear, I am new to sql and new to stackoverflow,  I understand your point, but please go easy on me